How Can I Ethically Adjust Grading Without Violating My 'No Grade Curving' Policy?
I always tell my students that I don't curve their grades, and that their final exam and quiz scores will directly determine their letter grades. I do this to avoid giving them false hope that they might still pass if the majority of students perform poorly.
However, in practice, I often adjust the grading rubrics to ensure that the average grades aren’t too high or too low, especially when the assessments turn out to be easier or harder than intended. This adjustment process makes me feel uneasy, as it feels like I'm effectively curving the grades despite my claim that I won’t.
How can I handle this dilemma ethically? Should I revise my policy, or is there a better way to approach grading adjustments without feeling like I'm compromising academic integrity? Or is there better way to gauge how difficult or easy an exam/quiz would be?
BTW, I do let students retake a portion of the quizzes and I drop the lowest grade of the quizzes.

My aim for not curving the grade is to discourage students to assume they will pass even if they get only something like 36% of the points, which some of my colleagues do. And I also want to avoid student come to beg for more points.
My aim for adjust rubrics is that some times I think a problem is very easy, which turn out not to be the case for most students.

Do you change the rubric before or after you see the exam outcomes?

@Buffy I change them after I see the average grades.

I think the issue here is your 'no grade curving' policy - it seems unlikely that your exercises and test are so finely tuned to the material that no curving is needed.

Start with outlining what it is you want to achieve. Both with your "no curve" policy, and with your tinkering with the rubric. You can't set up good policies and strategies if you don't know what it is you want.

At the risk of sounding glib, I genuinely fail to see what the dilemma is supposed to be here. You can both (1) communicate to your students that you may curve your exams if you misjudge their difficulty and (2) communicate to your students not to "assume they will pass even if they get only something like 36% of the points". "It feels like I'm effectively curving the grades despite my claim that I won’t" – yes, this is precisely what you are doing.

@AdamPřenosil The thing is if I say that I " may curve your exams if you misjudge their difficulty", they always come to argue that the exam is too difficult.

I don't think that this is a big problem, but if you do, I am sure you can also figure out how to convey the message that you reserve the right to fine-tune the grades but also discourage student complaints. (Note: I don't think discouraging student complaints is necessarily a good thing, it's better instead to just get comfortable with saying "no" to students, but that's a separate discussion.)

The idea of curving is to ensure that you hit some distribution of grades (e.g. you want to make sure that 10% of your students get As, 20% get Bs, and so on).  What you are describing does not seem like this.  Rather, you are adjusting the relationship between score and letter grade to reflect errors or unfairness introduced in the writing of the exam.  This is totally different, and I don't think that you should have any qualms about it.

When you say "to encourage students to assume they will pass," do you actually mean "to discourage students from assuming they will pass"?

@shoover Yes. I have updated it.

@LeafGlowPath Have you, in the past, actually adjusted grades only to reach a certain number or percentage of (some) grades (e.g. "at least one person should get an A" / "not more than 50% of students shall fail")? Or did you only do this if an assessment turned out to be easier or harder than expected?

Perhaps what you really want is a set of rules around how and when grades will or will not be curved that can be communicated to your students? So you have leeway to set a curve based on the distribution of student performance, but also have students know that they can't change only their grade by arguing over difficulty?

Fundamentally grading needs to be fair to every individual. If a good grade by X results in a lower grade for Y then it is fundamentally unfair as the grade no longer depends on the efforts and skills of Y alone, but on something they can't control.
No individual class has a predictable distribution of skills and none will closely match the distribution of the population from which it is drawn. So, you can't make assumptions.
Suppose, hypothetically, that you have a class with 30 students and they happen to be the "best" 30 students on the planet. Assuming, hypothetically, that they are properly engaged, then they will all get full marks in any fair system. Any system that guarantees failure (or low marks) for some of those students is fundamentally unfair.
So, a grading rubric should be constructed when the exam is constructed and "points" per question should be determined at that time. You then live with those decisions (caveat below). If they all deserve top marks based on those decisions then they should get them.
What you can do is, in future delivery of that course, make the rubric a bit lower or make the questions harder. I used to put one very hard (near impossible) question on every exam and warn the students that it would be there. I didn't give it especially large weight, but it would tell me who was excelling in the study of the material.
Caveat. You can advantage a student slightly as long as it doesn't disadvantage other students. So, if 90 was required for A, then 89 would probably also get an A. This only recognizes that my questions aren't perfect and might be misunderstood and my grading isn't perfect either, requiring some small grained decision making on answers. If I'm not perfect, then my grading scheme isn't perfect, so some sloppiness is included so that no one is disadvantaged.
Another practice of mine was, at the end of the course, look at the grade distribution (actually the numeric total, not the letter grades). I'd make a determination informally whether I thought that distribution matched what I considered the actual learning of the students generally (I had reasonable scale for this: 30 or so students.). If I thought the distribution was too low, I'd up it a bit, giving everyone a bonus, raising the distribution. No one was disadvantaged. Students considered me "tough but fair". People didn't pass without effort, but if the effort and results were there, students got what they considered a fair grade. Aim for that.
I've had classes where every student is excellent and so the distribution of grades is naturally at the high end. There is nothing wrong with that. I do my job. They do theirs. Fairness over all.
Changing the rubric after seeing the grades can hardly be fair. It makes grading something other than skill-building into a competition where the students don't actually have any idea of the rules until after the exam.
If department heads and deans complain that your grades are too high, explain the above and defend the students. Toughen the course for the future, if you like. And if you see grades higher than your judgement of the overall skills early enough, toughen the course for future exams. But after the fact downward adjustments are just wrong.

Thanks. It's more often that I adjust the rubrics to increase the average. But I do see your point and will try to stick to pre-defined rubrics.

Though, rubrics cannot really be entirely designed before grading. Sometimes students make mistakes in ways I did not expect, and I have to judge on the spot how much partial points to take.

@LeafGlowPath: Regarding rubrics, my comments to this Academia SE answer briefly discuss what I did, such as: As for the rubric, this was often a "work in progress" in the sense that I made grading decisions whenever a certain type of error showed up, rather than trying to anticipate them in advance. As for my grading in general, see this Academia SE answer and this Mathematics Educators answer.

"Changing the rubric after seeing the grades can hardly be fair" - I agree, but just want to point out that sometimes "seeing the grades" causes a realization that some external factor caused a shift and I support responding to that if it harms no students.

I don't think it is unfair if the grade of X depends on the grade of Y. Grading can be understood to measure (absolute) skill, but it can also be understood to measure your relative strength, i.e. the percentile you are in. Different people have different approaches to this.

The Hunger Games, then, @JFabianMeier?

The computer science department I studied in worked exactly like this. Exam cohorts ("Classes" in the American sense I think) were small, so that it was sometimes the case all students did very well, eg half with first class, and sometimes they generally did badly. There is a correlation effect as well - good students can pull up those around them. Assuming a normal curve is a very bad assumption for many real populations.

@Buffy If the question is "Has person X mastered a certain skill?", then you need absolute grading. If you need to fill a limited number of positions, then you need relative grading. It does not help you if everyone has an A.

@JFabianMeier "then you need relative grading" -- not necessarily. If every candidate for a position has an absolute A grade, it means, practically, that they are all fully and equally qualified with respect to what that grade can measure. Rather than trying to amplify small differences that are likely noise, you would be better served by weighting other meaningful qualifications for the position. Or, maybe in the future you should require a tougher course/test where the absolute grade will properly distinguish your candidates.

@nanoman You are right, you should not try to find small differences to generate arbitrary grades. But you should also be careful not to set a very low hurdle, and everyone jumps over it and gets an A. Often, I am not mainly interested in people with a given skill, but people who are intelligent, and -- lacking other measures -- getting better grades than 95% of the rest is an indicator of intelligence.

Making good exams and quizes is more of an art than a science.
When I design a test, then I do that with the goal that anyone who knows everything I taught during my lectures should get 100%. But people actually acing a test is very rare. When a student answers a question wrong, then there are three possible reasons:

It's the student's fault, because they didn't pay attention or didn't study.
It's my fault as a teacher, because I didn't teach that thing properly or didn't properly communicate its importance.
It's my fault as a test author, because I phrased the question in an awkward way and the student had no idea what I actually wanted from them.

If it's the students fault, that's on them and they deserve the bad grade. If it's my fault, then I might want to consider being lenient on grading. But how can I tell?
Usually by looking at the results for an individual question in isolation. If everyone got a question wrong, including people who answered most other questions correctly, then it was probably my fault and the question wasn't possible to solve. I might want to reduce the number of points for that question or remove it from grading altogether. But if there are some students who answered a question correctly, then it seems like it was indeed possible to answer it, and those who didn't should lose their points for it.

The rationale of "curving" as you call it is (at least in many places) to produce the same average or distribution of grades in every course. The idea behind that is that this makes grades comparable across courses (and particularly when different people teach the same course at different times), but obviously it will bias things if one group of students in a course as a whole is stronger than another, which can easily happen.
You don't want to do this kind of thing, and I agree with you (assuming that there is no general policy in your university that prescribes this).
There is however another issue, which is that we may sometimes assess the time required for an assessment wrong, or we may misjudge the difficulty of some questions.
In fact we'd be happy to grade so that grades over different courses and different runs of the same course are comparable and fair, but this is not achieved by "curving". If possible, this should be achieved by qualitative descriptors of what the different grades mean in terms of competences and understanding of the students.
A personal grading policy could be guided by such descriptors, which allow for the possibility that some groups of students are just overall better than others (so no "curving"), but they also allow for the possibility to adjust the grading scheme in case that, for example, questions turn out easier or more difficult or more time consuming than expected.
It should be possible to communicate this to the students, making clear that (a) "curving" will not happen but (b) adjustments may happen (for good reasons).

Your second topic: "Should I curve?"
When I taught, I looked at the median average.  I ordered the scores from high to low and looked at the one in the middle.  If that one was below 75 then everyone in the class got the same amount of points added:  Whatever it took to get the middle score up to 75.
Example:
Abby:    95 +12 = 107 (recorded as 100)
Bob:     63 +12 = 75
Cedrick: 36 +12 = 48
My reasoning was that if average wasn't at least C, something was wrong.  I wasn't teaching well enough.  The material was too hard.  (Good reasons to curve).  I got a bad batch of students.  Too many of them arrived lacking prerequisite skills. (Bad reasons to curve).  If you feel like you can 'smell' why students weren't doing well then you'd have a better idea as to whether you should curve.  If you have taught your classes 3 times or less then I'd say curves are on the table.  You'll continually build better curricula, methods, and ideas about what students can accomplish.
Your first topic: "Is changing my rubrics curving?"
Are you changing rubrics after students have received grades so that the next batch of students has different rubrics?  That's improving your classes and not curving.
Are you changing rubrics so that students will get different grades on the current test/assignment?
Sub question: Did the students clearly receive the rubrics you are using to grade?
Yes > then yes, that is curving.
No > it's curving, but only you will know.  You get to decide whether it's ethical.

My experience as a (former) student: in my University, it was a general rule that a gaussian curve must be applied before providing the grades for a final exam. In practice, what most professors would do is to grade each test (which were always MCQs in our case) according to the agreed-upon grading rubrics, compute score, and students who scored under 50% of maximum score achievable would fail. After that, the final grade would be given by dividing the score of each student by the highest score achieved by a student. I found this system to be good, because:

Passing/failing would not be influenced by what others did, only by how each student fared against the exam questions.
There would be always a perfect grade, even though nobody got some questions right (if the questions were too hard or not correctly written).
Worst case scenario, if there were a student that aced the exam, everyone would get their grade according to the grading scheme. (Although in practice this rarely happened, and virtually nobody got a barely passing grade because not even top students would manage to ace the exams, but rather students would either fail or get one grade upper than the passing grade.)
Adjustments were done always in favor of the student.
If all students would be top performers, all would get (near) perfect scores.

The main caveat of this method would be that students could theoretically ally and ask the top performers to underperform intentionally, in order for bottom of class to get a higher grade, but this never happened because 1. This was a competitive environment (there were incentives for top students) and 2. Top students wouldn't risk having a bad day and accidentally fail by over-underperforming.

Re your worst case scenario: It's always possible to ignore the one outlier. I once managed to score 78/80 in an exam where "common knowledge" said that 65-70 was the best that could be achieved in practice. So when doing the usual adjustments, they would not take my 78 as the "highest student score" but the 70 (or something, I don't remember exactly) scored by the second best student.

If you ask questions of somewhat different difficulty year to year, then it makes sense that the exact percentage grade needed to obtain an A, B, ... would vary from year to year.
It's hard to tell exactly how hard a question is until the you see the students' performance, so it makes sense to set the grade cutoffs based on student performance to some extent.
This is kind of a curve, since you'd be lowering the standard needed to achieve a grade and, to an extent, lowering it more if students struggled more. But it's definitely a different type of curve than deciding in advance how many As, Bs, etc you will give out.
In some of my classes, I follow this kind of policy. At the end of the term, I rank students by percentage grade in the class, and look back at students' work. If a lot of students in the 87-90% range are doing what I'd call A-level work, I may drop the cutoff for an A down to 87%. And so on.
Also, if you don't worry about designing the rubric to give the right average number of points, you can focus better on designing it to assess knowledge.

Curving and adjusting mean the same thing, and I recall being shocked (as a teaching assistant) when a professor who professed no curve explicitly told us to calculate the median and other statistics and assure that about top 10% get A's and so on. Whether it actually works on students is hard to say - some children learn early on that parents and teachers often fail to make good on their promises/threats.
However, as a teaching assistant I also adopted a lenient policy that I would add a few points here and there in an appeal. My justification is that, if a student bothered to come to the appeal, and especially if they bothered to figure out or to ask for a correct solution of the problems, they deserve a few extra points. This is especially true for those who had been generally diligent students, but had a bad day on the exam. One could even stretch this philosophy by saying that the exam does not end when the papers are collected, but only when the final grades are submitted to the administration.
